# android studio JSON response from URL connected through VPN

Tags: java, android, json, url, response

I have the following code working for any sample URL with a JSON

```
package com.example.carlos.jsoninputurl;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.carlos.jsoninputurl.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnHit;
    TextView txtJson;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnHit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
        txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

        btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new JsonTask().execute("https://10.109.143.88:8443/getsensorvalues/2741025");

                //working url:  http://validate.jsontest.com/?json=%7B%22key%22:%22value%22%7D
                //not working url: https://10.109.143.88:8443/getsensorvalues/2741025
            }
        });


    }


    private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();


                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line).append("\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error due to a malformed URL " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            txtJson.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

the URL from JSON placeholder website works as I want, it shows the the following output on a textview.

```
{
   "object_or_array": "object",
   "empty": false,
   "parse_time_nanoseconds": 13932,
   "validate": true,
   "size": 1
}
```

But when I try the other website, it doesn't show anything.
Since it is a private IP I am connected to the VPN.
Going to the URL in web browser gives the following output:

```
{"requestResult":"SUCCESS","values":[{"variableName":"Temperature","value":{"value":99.0,"timeStamp":"10.06.2017 11:10 PM"}},{"variableName":"Pressure","value":{"value":99.0,"timeStamp":"10.06.2017 11:03 PM"}},{"variableName":"Humidity","value":null}],"pantherId":2741025}
```

Accessing the website through the VPN does give a certificate error, but it is a trusted school URL for testing a sensor app.
Any suggestion on how to modify the code to be able to get the json response working on the app?

Comment: can you show me how you have created your POJO class?